# Creating a XML parser in Swift 1.2

Tags: xml, swift, parsing

I realize that this question has been asked over an over again, and that there are multiple choices of tutorials to go through, by doing a google search.

However, it seems that whatever code the answerers or tutorials provide do not work for me. I get several errors.

Can someone tell me how you create a successful XML parser/reader in Swift? Or link me to a tutorial that they themselves have successful experience with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to create an xml parser, or are you looking for a library which parses xml? If it's the former why not read the source of existing parsers and see how they work?

Comment: There are many examples of this and an easy search will find it

Answer (score 0):

You wont have a chance to fail if you use this awesome library:

```
https://github.com/tadija/AEXML
```

I use it in my game and it is easy as hell